# Unable to debug airflow error.Trying to use airflow to build data pipeline on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

### **I am trying to identify what might be causing the below issue (Airflow)?**

Basically I have written a Test DAG and it's main task is to read data from BigQuery and write it into a new table.I tried searching about this but I am not able to find out what might be causing this. I'm not even sure if my gcp_connection is working correctly. I don't know how to test this.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/subdag_operator.py", line 103, in execute
    executor=self.executor)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 4214, in run
    job.run()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 203, in run
    self._execute()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 2547, in _execute
    raise AirflowException(err)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: ---------------------------------------------------
Some task instances failed:
{('test_oscope.test_oscope', 'create_if_not_exists', datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), 1), ('test_oscope.test_oscope', 'fill', datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<Timezone [UTC]>), 1)}
```

Comment: please provide your DAG as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks in Airflow are very useful on their own to use in interactive environments like iPython or Jupyter Notebook.

For example:

```py
from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook

GCSHook = GoogleCloudStorageHook(google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_conn_id')
GCSHook.get_conn() # This will check if your GCP connection is working correctly or not
```